# Can't log user in automatically after account creation in AngularFire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebasesimplelogin

Hello I am using AngularJS + Firebase with Angular Fire, trying to create a simple tumblr-like blog app to learn the ins and outs of AngularJS. Not using any angular-seeds or going off a specific tutorial, just sort of learning things as I need to.

I got the $firebase simple login system working. I created a simple user registration form and when the user submits I fire $createUser() which works, and then I load all the profile data the user enters into a data set with the user.id returned by the createUser promise. The API doc says that their is an argument that left blank will automatically log the user in after creation, however I read in several places that this was taken out, and the doc left unupdated. Also in the regular Firebase API it mentions that a user must be logged in after account creation. I tried firing the $login() method inside the returned promise of the account creation like so:

```
$scope.signUp = function(newuser){
                var userData = newuser;
                var userRef = new Firebase(FB_URL+'users');
                $scope.users = $firebase(userRef); //oooohhhhhh
                $rootScope.loginObj.$createUser(newuser.email,newuser.password).then(function(user){
                    var child = $scope.users.$child(user.id);
                    child.$set({name:userData.fullname,email:userData.email});
                    $rootScope.loginObj.$login('password',userData.email,userData.password).then(function(user,error){
                        $location.path('/home');
                    },function(error){
                        console.log(error);
                    });
                    //$rootScope.loginObj.user = user;
                    //$rootScope.currentUser = user;
                    //$location.path('/home');
                    //$rootScope.loginObj.$login('password', userData.email, userData.password).then(function(user){
                    //  $location.path('/home');
                    //},function(error){
                    //  console.log(error);
                    //});
                },function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                });
            };
```

And its throwing me this error:

```
        Error {code: "UNKNOWN_ERROR", data: Object, stack: "Error: FirebaseSimpleLogin: FirebaseSimpleLogin: A…ple-login/1.5.0/firebase-simple-login.js:188:231)", message: "FirebaseSimpleLogin: FirebaseSimpleLogin: An unknown error occurred."}
code: "UNKNOWN_ERROR"
data: Object
message: "FirebaseSimpleLogin: FirebaseSimpleLogin: An unknown error occurred."
stack: "Error: FirebaseSimpleLogin: FirebaseSimpleLogin: An unknown error occurred.↵    at Error (native)↵    at Object.fb.simplelogin.Errors.format (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.5.0/firebase-simple-login.js:33:294)↵    at https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.5.0/firebase-simple-login.js:176:275↵    at fb.simplelogin.providers.Password_.login (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.5.0/firebase-simple-login.js:90:196)↵    at https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.5.0/firebase-simple-login.js:176:209↵    at r (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.5.0/firebase-simple-login.js:60:151)↵    at new n (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.5.0/firebase-simple-login.js:60:79)↵    at fb.simplelogin.client.loginWithPassword (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.5.0/firebase-simple-login.js:176:81)↵    at fb.simplelogin.client.login (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.5.0/firebase-simple-login.js:173:85)↵    at Object.login (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.5.0/firebase-simple-login.js:188:231)"
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
__proto__: d
```

I also tried calling the method I created inside the controller which is similar $scope.login(email,password), but that didnt work either. When the user registers, its suppose to take them to a home view thats restricted to logged in users. if the user isn't authenticated then it bounces them back to the login view. So as it is now, the user creates their account then gets routed to /home, they aren't showing up as authenticated and then bounces the back to login.
My router config:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', 
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
   .when('/admin', {
    templateUrl: 'admin.html',
    controller: 'AdminController',
    needsAuth: true
  })
  .when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'HomeController',
    needsAuth: true
  })
  .when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'app/html/login-form.html',
    controller: 'LogInController',
    needsAuth: false
  })
  .otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
}]);
```

And here is the logic that checks if a user is authenticated once a routechange is started:

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $firebaseSimpleLogin, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next, $firebaseSimpleLogin, $scope, $rootScope) {
        //console.log(event.targetScope);

        console.log(event.targetScope.currentUser);
        event.targetScope.loginObj.$getCurrentUser().then(function(user){ 

            var userAuthenticated = null;
            if (user || event.targetScope.currentUser)
                var userAuthenticated =  true;

            //console.log(userAuthenticated);
            if(!userAuthenticated && next.needsAuth){
                $location.path('/login');
            }
        }, function(error){
            console.log(error);

        });
    });
```

I tried circumnavigating the problem by creating a separate variable called currentUser and loading it with the user data returned by createUser function, and then checking for that too when it takes them to the home view. And it works, but then if the user refreshes they lose that information because its not being saved to the session which I'm guessing is what $login does.

Answer (score 0):

The [second argument to $login](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/blob/master/angularfire.js#L863) is not an email address and password (like createUser) but an object; the same API as the core FirebaseSimpleLogin method.

So this code:

```
$rootScope.loginObj.$login('password',userData.email,userData.password).then(...)
```

Should look more like this:

```
var options = {email: userData.email, password: userData.password};
$rootScope.loginObj.$login('password', options).then(...)
```

See the [API docs on $login](https://www.firebase.com/docs/angular/reference.html#login-provider-options) for more details and examples.